# GCC v.4 compilation error with #pragma omp task (variables with reference type are not permitted in private/firstprivate clauses)

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, task, openmp, gcc4

I am porting one large MPI-based physics code to OpenMP tasking. On one Cray supercomputing machine the code compiled, linked and runs perfectly (cray-mpich library, Cray compiler were used for this). Then, the code moved to a server for Jenkins continuous integration (I don't have admin rights on that server), and there is only GCC v.4 compiler (Cray compiler can't be used as it's not a Cray machine). On that server my code is not compiled, there is an error:

```
... error: ‘pcls’ implicitly determined as ‘firstprivate’ has reference type
    #pragma omp task
            ^
```

It's a spaghetti code, so it's hard to copy-paste here the code lines caused this error, but my guess is that this is due to the problem described here:
http://forum.openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=117

Is there any possibility to solve this issue? It seems like with GCC v.6 this was resolved, but not sure... I am curious if someone has this situation...

UPD:
I am providing the skeleton of one function, where one such error is caused (sorry for long listing!):

```
void EMfields3D::sumMoments_vectorized(const Particles3Dcomm* part)
{
  grid_initialisation(...);
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    for (int species_idx = 0; species_idx < ns; species_idx++)
    {
      const Particles3Dcomm& pcls = part[species_idx];
      assert_eq(pcls.get_particleType(), ParticleType::SoA);
      const int is = pcls.get_species_num();
      assert_eq(species_idx,is);

      double const*const x = pcls.getXall();
      double const*const y = pcls.getYall();
      double const*const z = pcls.getZall();
      double const*const u = pcls.getUall();
      double const*const v = pcls.getVall();
      double const*const w = pcls.getWall();
      double const*const q = pcls.getQall();

      const int nop = pcls.getNOP();
      #pragma omp master
      {
        start_timing_for_moments_accumulation(...);
      }
      ...
      #pragma omp for // because shared
        for(int i=0; i<moments1dsize; i++)
          moments1d[i]=0;

      // prevent threads from writing to the same location
      for(int cxmod2=0; cxmod2<2; cxmod2++)
        for(int cymod2=0; cymod2<2; cymod2++)
        // each mesh cell is handled by its own thread
          #pragma omp for collapse(2)
            for(int cx=cxmod2;cx<nxc;cx+=2)
              for(int cy=cymod2;cy<nyc;cy+=2)
                for(int cz=0;cz<nzc;cz++)
                  #pragma omp task
                  {
                    const int ix = cx + 1;
                    const int iy = cy + 1;
                    const int iz = cz + 1;
                    {
                      // reference the 8 nodes to which we will
                      // write moment data for particles in this mesh cell.
                      //
                      arr1_double_fetch momentsArray[8];
                      arr2_double_fetch moments00 = moments[ix][iy];
                      arr2_double_fetch moments01 = moments[ix][cy];
                      arr2_double_fetch moments10 = moments[cx][iy];
                      arr2_double_fetch moments11 = moments[cx][cy];
                      momentsArray[0] = moments00[iz]; // moments000 
                      momentsArray[1] = moments00[cz]; // moments001 
                      momentsArray[2] = moments01[iz]; // moments010 
                      momentsArray[3] = moments01[cz]; // moments011 
                      momentsArray[4] = moments10[iz]; // moments100 
                      momentsArray[5] = moments10[cz]; // moments101 
                      momentsArray[6] = moments11[iz]; // moments110 
                      momentsArray[7] = moments11[cz]; // moments111 

                      const int numpcls_in_cell = pcls.get_numpcls_in_bucket(cx,cy,cz);
                      const int bucket_offset = pcls.get_bucket_offset(cx,cy,cz);
                      const int bucket_end = bucket_offset+numpcls_in_cell;

                      some_manipulation_with_moments_accumulation(...);

                    }
                }

      #pragma omp master
      {
        end_timing_for_moments_accumulation(...);
      }

      // reduction
      #pragma omp master
      {
        start_timing_for_moments_reduction(...);
      }

      {
        #pragma omp for collapse(2)
          for(int i=0;i<nxn;i++)
          {
            for(int j=0;j<nyn;j++)
            {
              for(int k=0;k<nzn;k++)
                #pragma omp task
                {
                  rhons[is][i][j][k] = invVOL*moments[i][j][k][0];
                  Jxs  [is][i][j][k] = invVOL*moments[i][j][k][1];
                  Jys  [is][i][j][k] = invVOL*moments[i][j][k][2];
                  Jzs  [is][i][j][k] = invVOL*moments[i][j][k][3];
                  pXXsn[is][i][j][k] = invVOL*moments[i][j][k][4];
                  pXYsn[is][i][j][k] = invVOL*moments[i][j][k][5];
                  pXZsn[is][i][j][k] = invVOL*moments[i][j][k][6];
                  pYYsn[is][i][j][k] = invVOL*moments[i][j][k][7];
                  pYZsn[is][i][j][k] = invVOL*moments[i][j][k][8];
                  pZZsn[is][i][j][k] = invVOL*moments[i][j][k][9];
                }
            }
          }
      }

      #pragma omp master
      {
        end_timing_for_moments_reduction(...);
      }

    }

  }

  for (int i = 0; i < ns; i++)
  {
    communicateGhostP2G(i);
  }

}
```

Please, don't try to find a logic here (like why there is "#pragma omp parallel" and then the for-loop appears without "#pragma omp for"; or why in a for-loop there is a task construct)... I was not implementing the code, but I has to port it to OpenMP tasking...

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly specify the data sharing mode? Looking at the link you provided, that seems the cause of the error. `#pragma omp task firstprivate(pcls)`

Comment: That such code compiles with the Cray compiler seems like undefined behaviour to me.

Comment: @HristoIliev, moreover, the sysadmin of the Jenkins server finally installed GCC v.6, it compiled this code(!) without any errors (particularly, like I described above), but then couldn't linked, because some libraries on the server were compiled with the old version of GCC, so the admin is working on this.

But if the code was only compiled with GCC v.6, is it a good sign? :)

Comment: @JorgeBellón, the thing is that I don't want 'pcls' to be firstprivate, but this is forced somehow by "#pragma omp task" (I don't know why). In this task construct, this 'pcls' is used (at least directly, but it might be used through numerous spaghetti-style references) as:
`const int numpcls_in_cell = pcls.get_numpcls_in_bucket(cx,cy,cz);
 const int bucket_offset = pcls.get_bucket_offset(cx,cy,cz);`

Comment: I updated my question